# Spring Boot: Download file directly from directory with file URI

Tags: spring-boot

Assume that I have a directory for uploaded public files like images in `/var/my-project/upload/public`.
I want to download files in `public` directory with its name. For example if there is a file named `product-image.png` in `public` directory with uri `/var/my-project/upload/public/product-image.png`, access to this file with this url: `http://mysite/public/product-image.png`.
I know how to use a controller for this purpose, but I want to know is there a way to directly access these files without using a controller method?

Answer (score 0):

The only *acceptable* way of doing it is with a ReSTful api. There are other methods such as ftp, but When you use ftp, Files can be added by anyone who knows how. With a ReST controller, you define what can be added beforehand. In fact, with a controller you define just about everything regarding that endpoint.

So the short answer is (especially if you are using Spring boot) use an API, lest you not regret it later.

When I was in College, our website had a built in "back door" to a certain endpoint via ftp. Some kids in one of my classes found out about that back door and let themselves inside. Needless to say' they didnt bother wiping their shoes on the mat on their way in.

The moral: Never assume that your resources aren't worth messing with. All you need to do is make it unsecure, and people will eventually mess with it.

Comment: The whole point of frameworks like spring boot is to remove these types of concern from off the developer's lap. This way you can focus more on the code on the other side of that endpoint.

Comment: Upload process is secured but downloading has no need to be secure. These are product images and once user opens website landing page, there are about 60 images in the page. I think this will be a performance issue hitting controller method for each image.

Comment: Look up "http PUSH" on google. With http3  each user only downloads resources once. every other time they should be cached. Although I am not sure of the details. http3 is new and I haven't had time to read into it. My advice is to test it out. In spring boot / MVC it only takes a minute to write a controller. Especially if you already have the DB and repos set up.

Comment: @Ali Behzadian Nejad Ftp _is_ faster than http, but if you are thinking about trying it, do the researching it, do the research. SSL is supported, so users are safe. I just nont know about the server. BTW you should also look up [gatling](https://gatling.io/) . It is a load tester for spring boot. It was made for situations like yours. gl